# Standalone class generating method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails application an ad hoc class is defined

```
class TwitterClient
  BASE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/2/"

  def initialize(twitter_account)
    @twitter_account = twitter_account
    Rails.logger.info(@twitter_account.inspect)
  end

  def me
    path = BASE_URL.to_s + 'users/me'
    get(path)
  end

  private

  def get(path)
    request(:get, path)
  end
end
```

Verifying via the console, an object can be created

```
 c = TwitterAccount.first
=>
#<TwitterAccount:0x00000001086c5c10
```

however, calling the `me` method on that object `c.me` returns an error:

```
.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.4/lib/active_model/  
attribute_methods.rb:458:in `method_missing': undefined method `me' for #<TwitterAccount
```

Where is this mistake?

Comment: `c` does not seem to be an instance of `TwitterClient` but of `TwitterAccount`
if you want to have access to a method in the `TwitterClient` class you need to create an instance of it
`twitter_client = TwitterClient.new(twitter_account)`
then you can access `me` like `twitter_client.me`

Comment: right-o.  Eyes cannot see sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may as well stick it as an answer to help other devs stuck out there,

`c` does not seem to be an instance of `TwitterClient` but of `TwitterAccount`. If you want to have access to a method in the `TwitterClient` class you need to create an *instance* of it:

`twitter_client = TwitterClient.new(twitter_account)`

then you can access the `me` method like:

`twitter_client.me`